# Puppeteer waitForNavigation reliability in determining page URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've got a Puppeteer Node JS app that, given a starting URL, follows the URL and scrapes the window's URL of each page it identifies. Originally I was using a `setInterval` and getting the current URL every 250ms but have stumbled upon the `waitForNavigation` option and need to know whether what I've got is going to be reliable?

Given the starting URL, I need to identify all of the pages, and just the pages that Puppeteer goes through, and then with a `setTimeout` make the assumption that if Puppeteer hasn't redirected to a new page within a given period of time, assume that there's no more redirections.

Will `page.waitForNavigation` work for this intended behaviour?

My current JS is:

```js
let evalTimeout;

// initiate a Puppeteer instance with options and launch
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: argOptions,
  headless: (config.puppeteer.run_in_headless === 'true') ? true : false
});

// launch a new page
const page = await browser.newPage();

// go to a URL
await page.goto(body.url);

// create a function to inject into the page to scrape data
const currentUrl = () => {
  return window.location.href;
}

// log the current page every 250ms
async function scrapePageUrl (runOnce = false) {
  try {
    console.log('running timeout...')

    if (!runOnce) {
      evalTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('6s reached, running omce')
        scrapePageUrl(true) // assumes no more redirections after 6s, get final URL
      }, 6000)
    }

    const url = await page.evaluate(currentUrl);
    if (!runOnce) await page.waitForNavigation();

    console.log(`url: ${url}`)

    if (!runOnce) {
      clearTimeout(evalTimeout)
      scrapePageUrl()
    }

  } catch (err) { }
}

scrapePageUrl()
```

Comment: This looks like a race condition -- multiple pages are going to be overwriting `evalTimeout`. What is a sample page and output you expect, so I can provide a working example, please? `waitForNavigation` is a better tool but it's hard to tell if it's going to work as is -- usually, it needs to be coupled in a `Promise.all` with an action that causes a navigation, like `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click(sel)])`.

Comment: For example, `page.goto(body.url)` starts on a page, such as https://example.com/, let's assume this page has a `setTimeout` that redirects to https://google.com/ after 3 seconds and then never redirects thereafter. The `currentUrl` is logged for https://example.com/ and on the next scrape, https://google.com/ never redirects, so reaches the 6s limit in this case and then does something, for example, logs all of the page URLs into an array

Comment: So you want to follow redirects until you reach a page that doesn't redirect? Puppeteer should automatically follow redirects, no? Do you have a better example of the target page than example.com, which doesn't actually redirect? Your description makes sense conceptually, but it's rather vague and abstract, so a live URL or minimal set of HTML/JS files that you can inject locally would make it much clearer what you need.